Find the value of the tangent segment PC in the circle below
In the figure if PH = 15m, HT = 8m and the radius of the semicircle is 13 m.
Calculate PC with P and T tangency points. (Answer:$\frac{13\sqrt3}{3}$)

I try:
$\triangle PCO: OC^2 = CP^2+PO^2 = \implies OC^2 = CP^2+13^2$
$PCOH$ is cyclic
$PCTO is cyclic
$ \triangle CHB: CB~2=CH^2+BH^2$
$PC  = PT$
$OC$ is angle bissector $\triangle OPT_{(isosc)} \implies OC \perp PT$
According to geogebra, the POC angle measures $30$ degrees but I was unable to demonstrate it and the problem would be solved.


is $PC$ parallel to $OH$?

@DS   No...As the problem was not mentioned, we cannot consider it as a parallel

Note that $OPCH$ and $OCTH$ are cyclic quadrilaterals. Therefore using Ptolemy's theorem on each, we can derive the equations:
$$OP\cdot CH+OH\cdot PC=PH\cdot OC$$
$$13CH+OH\cdot PC=15OC\tag1$$
$$HT\cdot OC+OH\cdot CT=OT\cdot CH$$
$$8OC+OH\cdot PC=13CH\tag2$$
By solving these equations we get $OC=\frac{26}{23}CH.$
And using Pythagorean theorem, $OH=\frac{7\sqrt3}{23}CH.$
Thus, $OH:CH:OC=7\sqrt3:23:26.$
From equation (1), $$PC=15\frac{OC}{OH}-13\frac{CH}{OH}=\frac{13\sqrt3}3$$

Using geogebra, the solution provided is correct. The detail is that the $angle  POT$ that appears is $ 60^o$ and thus $tan 60.PC = 13 $ which results in $PC = \frac{13sqrt3}{3}$

I posted the resulting figure in geogebra above

$OH = \frac{\sqrt{147}}{23}CH = \frac{7\sqrt3}{23}CH$

Indeed I had miscalculated. I have corrected it now. Thanks for the comments.
